# DefaultHttpHeaderMapper allows customization but then does not perform exclusion logic

Tags: java, http-headers, spring-integration

Using Spring Integration 4.0.3.RELEASE, I see in the documentation that customization of the DefaultHttpHeaderMapper instances is supported but I am finding some unexpected results from doing so.

I have created a DefaultHttpHeaderMapper instance that allows for our proprietary header prefix in addition to the standard ones.

For example (response):

```
private static final String[] RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME_PATTERNS = {DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME_PATTERN, MY_HTTP_PREFIX_PATT};
...
mapper.setOutboundHeaderNames(RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME_PATTERNS);
```

I have done similar for the request side of things.

There are methods to set exclusions on the instance as well:

```
public void setExcludedOutboundStandardRequestHeaderNames(String[] excludedOutboundStandardRequestHeaderNames);
public void setExcludedInboundStandardResponseHeaderNames(String[] excludedInboundStandardResponseHeaderNames)
```

It appears the only place the exclusions might be processed in the class is in the `shouldMapOutboundHeader(String headerName)` method. **However, the exclusion pathway does not execute if customization has been done.**

Line 419: `if (this.outboundHeaderNames == HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADER_NAMES)`

Line 431: `else if (this.outboundHeaderNames == HTTP_REQUEST_HEADER_NAMES)`

Even though I also included the standard header set, these conditions aren't true since I also added my own header pattern. The effect is some standard headers that I need to be to be excluded (e.g. `Content-Length` for response, as set by default via the `HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADER_NAMES_INBOUND_EXCLUSIONS` field) are not being excluded.

It seems odd to me that headers can be set and exclusions can be set but if you don't use one of the static factory methods to create a completely unaltered instance, you're not going to get those exclusions removed.

I can think of a couple hacky ways around this, but since this seems like a simple enough use case (just adding my own header pattern) I am led to believe that I am not using the correct construct.

Any clarity on how I've misunderstood the use of this class or suggestions for another way would be appreciated.

---

**The use case is about preserving the correct default management of standard headers (e.g. http) even if proprietary headers are also needed.**

My use case seems pretty standard (recognizing that I am likely bias): Server and client pass messages back and forth via http gateways. The messages themselves can have 3 types of headers:

1. Standard headers for http functioning
2. My proprietary headers for specific server-client communication (my prefix)
3. Headers that can be added during internal processing but should be stripped out
   before going across the wire to the other side.

The issue surfaced when I upgraded from Spring Integration 2.1.0.RELEASE => 4.0.3.RELEASE. 
After the upgrade the `Content-Length` header was not being handled properly so the payload of the server's response was getting truncated (request payload was smaller). 
Some research showed things like:

- https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2006
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2744

The DefaultHeaderMapper of the 2.1.0.RELEASE didn't have the exclusion logic indicating that this Content-Length situation was being handled elsewhere so my custom instance didn't have any ill effect. 
In 4.0.3.RELEASE it seems that proper functioning of the Content-Length header relies on the exclusion logic now present in DefaultHeaderMapper. Since this doesn't get invoked because I had added my header pattern, the http communication does not work (response is mangled).

Comment: Another thing that seems mixed is the support of the provided shortcut patterns (the `HTTP_*_HEADER_NAME_PATTERN` fields). It works if you use them for `set*boundHeaderNames` argument values in that the mapper will check the associated default `HTTP_*_HEADER_NAMES` array. But again, the exclusion logic would not run, failing the same conditionals (lines 419 and 431).

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Exclusion works only when `outboundHeaderNames`equals to `HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADER_NAMES` (or `HTTP_REQUEST_HEADER_NAMES`) array.

You must be more specific and provide an info what you are going to achieve.

If want just exclude more existing standard headers (`HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADER_NAMES` or `HTTP_REQUEST_HEADER_NAMES`), you really should use `setExcludedOutboundStandard*HeaderNames` methods.

If you want add more headers, but don't want to use default `X-` user prefix, you can change it just to the `` (empty String).

If you want to filter some headers thereafter you, eh, have to override `fromHeaders` method.

I agree that it isn't so useful, would be great, if you have some thoughts about improvement and share them with us in the [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Thank you for pointing out to that!

Comment: I updated the description to include the use case. Would be happy to create a Jira issue if you think it's appropriate.

Comment: I indeed do set the userDefinedHeaderPrefix ="". 
If I remember correctly, the reason I didn't utilize this initally for my proprietary pattern was that a set of headers was defined in an enum that both the Server and Client depended on, e.g. value: `myHdr`. In testing, I saw a lack of symmetry: When `myHdr` was sent from the client, it was prefixed, `myPrefix-myHdr`, and in the server the prefix was not stripped to turn the header back into `myHdr` which is what the server also expected. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) Some things have changed since then, so I tried to set the userDefinedHeaderPrefix as you suggested (leaving everything else as default from the static factory methods) but I don't see how that comes into play: `userDefinedHeaderPrefix` is only utilized after `shouldMap*boundHeader` logic has already excluded such a header. And, yes, I see that my headers are stripped from the messages. Can you clarify the purpose of this field?